# Traffic meter plugin for Firefox

Tags: firefox, plugins

I've been using a plugin called Firefox Throttle that allowed the user to see the current data traffic in firefox. For example, if you were loading a Youtube video, in the plugin bar of the browser you could read the current download and upload traffic metered in kb/s.

Unfortunately this plugin isn't compatible with firefox 6 and changing the "maxVersion" value in the install.rdf file doesn't work.

Is there any plugin to meter the firefox traffic?

Answer (score 1):

Try out the Firefox addon called [Minimeter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/minimeter/).

> Monitor your provider's upload/download usage meter.

[image]

Comment: Mmmmmmmmmm, that plugin measures how much bandwidth do you have if your ISP has limits. It doesn't show the current download/upload rates.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue earlier. The only way to resolve it is to use a portable version of Firefox 3.6 and install Firefox throttle for it.

You can find firefox 3.6 portable [here.](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable/localization#legacy36)

Comment: :( that's too bad, I don't want to rollback to 3.6. Thanks anyway for the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The [StatusbarEx add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/statusbarex/) seems to do the job :

[image: image1]

The [Extended Statusbar add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/extended-statusbar/) will do a part of the job, but only for download (not for upload).
Another similar one is the [Download status add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/download-status/).

Comment: StatusbarEx counts all the traffic coming from your network card, so if i'm receiving a file through my local network and downloading another file through firefox the plugin will show the combined download speeds, so it doesn't replace firefox throttle :(

Comment: Download Status doesn't show any data in firefox 6 :(

Comment: Extended Statusbar seems to work ok, but shows the average speed. Also it gets stuck from time to time :(